# Defining animation direction when using multiple animations on same element

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have this:

```css
.about5 {
  animation: fade 4s ease forwards, warp 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(95deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes warp {
  50% {
    transform: translateZ(-10px) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(29deg) rotateY(-180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="about5">About</div>

<div class="about">About text etc</div>
```

Why, when I have separated multiple animations by a comma, will the second animation:

```
@keyframes warp {
50% {
transform: translateZ(-10px) rotateX(60deg) 
rotateZ(29deg) rotateY(-180deg);
}
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {.about {
animation: 
spin 20s linear infinite, warp 2s linear infinite; animation. 
delay: 4s;}}
```

not take effect?

I want `about`element to spin and `translateZ` but it's not working. Is this because of the comma in the wrong place?

Comment: your code works fine

Answer (score 0):

It works ok, your problem must be in another place:

```css
.about5 {
  animation: fade 16s ease forwards infinite, warp 4s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes warp {
  50% {
    transform: translateZ(-10px) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(29deg) rotateY(-180deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="about5">About</div>
<div class="about">About text etc</div>
```

Comment: It should spin and translateZ

Comment: The `about` element should spin and translateZ etc only in @media over 768px. At the moment it either spins or translatez